# How to add a new column to a view

Tags: sql

**First issue: Trying to copy the values from Column1 to Column2. When I add column 2 and use Update, all values become NULL. Here my code:**

*1) I update the values from Column1, as I need to change the commas*

`UPDATE Table SET Column1 = REPLACE(Column1,',','')`

*2) I create Column2*

`ALTER TABLE Table Add Column2 Nvarchar(255);`

*3) Copy values from Column1 to Column2*

`UPDATE Table SET Column1 = Column2`

When I copy the values, both columns (1 &2) only contains NULL values

**Second Issue: I am trying to add a column to a view. This is my code:**

First try: I found this code, but dont know how to add or what code to use. Ex: New_Col would be added as another column, but we didnt define it before, so I dont know how to do it.

```
  alter view myView as
  select field1,
         New_Col
    from table1
```

Comment: You can't just add a column to a view. Depending on dbms you can either alter the view definition, or drop and recreate the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing it opposite than you should; that's why you got null values in both columns.

You didn't specify which database you use; this is Oracle example, but should make sense elsewhere.

Sample table:

```
SQL> create table test (column1 varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test
  2    select 'Little, Foot' from dual union all
  3    select 'Scott, Tiger' from dual;

2 rows created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from test;

COLUMN1
--------------------
Little, Foot
Scott, Tiger
```

First update removes comma:

```
SQL> update test set column1 = replace(column1, ',', '');

2 rows updated.

SQL> select * from test;

COLUMN1
--------------------
Little Foot
Scott Tiger
```

Adding new column:

```
SQL> alter table test add column2 varchar2(20);

Table altered.
```

This is what you did next: put (empty) COLUMN2 contents into COLUMN1, which *overwrites* existing data with null values:

```
SQL> update test set column1 = column2;

2 rows updated.

SQL> select * from test;

COLUMN1              COLUMN2
-------------------- --------------------
```

Should've been

```
SQL> rollback;

Rollback complete.

SQL> select * from test;

COLUMN1              COLUMN2
-------------------- --------------------
Little Foot
Scott Tiger

SQL> update test set column2 = column1;

2 rows updated.

SQL> select * from test;

COLUMN1              COLUMN2
-------------------- --------------------
Little Foot          Little Foot
Scott Tiger          Scott Tiger
```

OK; that makes sense.

---

As of view issues: `create OR REPLACE` is useful.

View with only one column:

```
SQL> create or replace view v_test as
  2    select column1 from test;

View created.

SQL> select * From v_test;

COLUMN1
--------------------
Little Foot
Scott Tiger
```

As view is just a stored query, it doesn't contain any data, you can recreate it without any problems - just include another column. That operation won't invalidate other objects, you won't lose grants ... *nothing* (except that you'll have a new column):

```
SQL> create or replace view v_test as
  2    select column1, column2 from test;

View created.

SQL> select * From v_Test;

COLUMN1              COLUMN2
-------------------- --------------------
Little Foot          Little Foot
Scott Tiger          Scott Tiger

SQL>
```

---

In a comment, you asked whether you can create an empty column in a view. You *can*, but - what would be its purpose?

Here's an example: view's column named `memo` is empty (its contents is `null`):

```
SQL> create or replace view v_test as
  2  select ename, job, null memo
  3  from emp
  4  where deptno = 10;

View created.

SQL> select * from v_test;

ENAME      JOB       MEMO
---------- --------- --------------------
CLARK      MANAGER
KING       PRESIDENT
MILLER     CLERK
```

Describe shows that datatype is varchar2, but - no size:

```
SQL> desc v_test
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ENAME                                              VARCHAR2(10)
 JOB                                                VARCHAR2(9)
 MEMO                                               VARCHAR2
```

If you want to fix the size "issue", then cast null as e.g. varchar2(20):

```
SQL> create or replace view v_test as
  2  select ename, job, cast(null as varchar2(20)) as memo
  3  from emp
  4  where deptno = 10;

View created.

SQL> select * from v_test;

ENAME      JOB       MEMO
---------- --------- --------------------
CLARK      MANAGER
KING       PRESIDENT
MILLER     CLERK

SQL> desc v_test
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ENAME                                              VARCHAR2(10)
 JOB                                                VARCHAR2(9)
 MEMO                                               VARCHAR2(20)

SQL>
```

That looks better. However, once again: what is that column's purpose? You can't do much with it except select it, and you'd get *nothing* as it is empty. You can't update it because view is - as I said - just a stored query, it doesn't contain any data. If there was `memo` column in underlying table, you could update view which - in turn - updates table, but - why would you want to do that?

Comment: Thanks a lot! All worked out finally. One more thing: So, you cannot create an empty column in a view, right? Just selecting columns from other tables, but never a new one empty, right?

Comment: You're welcome. You *can* create empty column in a view, but its purpose is questionable. Have a look at edited answer, I posted some more info.

Comment: Thanks again! Well, my purpose was to practice queries, as I don't want to affect the mother table. What I wanted was to create a new column (Nemo) and past values from the old column 1. Just for practice purposes. I thought you could update columns and more but you right, its a view.

Answer (score -1):

I don't quite understand what issue you're having with the 2nd one but for your first issue, you've simply got the columns in the wrong places on your update statement. It should be:

```
UPDATE Table SET Column2 = Column1
```